# Import Gmail Contacts using ASP.NET MVC External Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail-api, google-authentication

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.5.2 with SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and I have applied the same code example by using [ASP.NET Auth Integration](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) external Login feature as well in my Application for Google.

I have just done the coding for Login using Gmail but I am not able to extract  / get contacts from gmail account of particular user after allow permission to access.

I have reffered [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/552508/ASP-NET-Import-Gmail-Contacts) article and want to try using it but I don't have to get their password for getting their contacts so how could I?

Before Allow Code:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
            {
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
                app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
                app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
                app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
                app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "my client id",
                ClientSecret = "client secret",
Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("GoogleAccessToken"
                            , context.AccessToken));
                        foreach (var claim in context.User)
                        {
                            var claimType = string.Format("urn:google:{0}", claim.Key);
                            string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                            if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType,
                                    claimValue, "xmlSchemaString", "Google"));
                        }
                    }
                }
};
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly");
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read");
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read");
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
}
```

After Allow Code:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
            public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
            {
                var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (loginInfo == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login");
                }

                // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
                var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        return View("Lockout");
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel data = new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel();
                        data.ExUsername = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).
                            Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                        data.ExFirstName = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName).
                            Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                        data.ExLastName = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname).
                            Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                        data.Email = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).
                            Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                        // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                        ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                }
            }
```

Please anyone who has done help me to solve this issue!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to post some code or we cant help you debug your problem.  I can tell you that Google contacts is a separate API with its own scope the user will have to authenticate with both mail and contacts I would suspect.

Comment: @DaImTo as per your suggestion I just update my question please look into that and yes I have just applied the general concept to allow Gmail users to access my application , in that nothing extra except getting their profile information basic like name, email, etc... but don't know how to access contacts?

Comment: We need to see your code not a link to an article you are following http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   Look at the contacts API remember you cant use login and password you are going to have to use Oauth2

Comment: @DaImTo Ok I just update my question with the code as much as I can give as per permission. Please now suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: http://www.daimto.com/google-contacts-with-c/ this is all I have really on the contracts api you haven't posted how you are making the requests to the API

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for reply I am trying using that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124258/discussion-between-padhiyar-and-daimto).